# To find out the user has which privileges in db2 database

Tags: database, db2, db2-luw

I want to find out users privileges list like which users have execute privileges, which users have admin / insert / update provileges like this.

I got the list of users present in the database from -
SELECT * FROM SYSIBMADM.AUTHORIZATIONIDS

But I can't differentiate them on basis of privileges they have

I got the list of users present in the database from -

SELECT * FROM SYSIBMADM.AUTHORIZATIONIDS

But I can't differentiate them on basis of privileges they ha
ve

Comment: Please format the question and add what you want as output. You can select the privileges on individual objects

Comment: Have you considered studying the documentation for the catalog tables like syscat.dbauth, syscat.tabauth, syscat.routineauth (and all syscat views whose names are like %AUTH%) ?

Answer (score 0):

To learn the details of how Db2-LUW stores database-authorities and user-permissions/privileges, you need to study the many and various catalog views that are in the catalog.

For example, `syscat.dbauth`, `syscat.tabauth`, `syscat.routineauth` etc. (and many more use name matches the pattern %AUTH%).

The [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=views-road-map-catalog) explains each of these views, you need to look at views use name matches the pattern %AUTH%.